# How to get the list of all User stories including child stories using /slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement API

Tags: rally

I am using this rally API to get the list of all the stories:

```
https://rally-n.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(Project.Name="My_Parent_Project")&order=OrderString
```

My_Parent_Project actually do not have any user stories, but its children projects (my_child_1 and my_child_2) has user stories.

Is there any specific field, which I can mention to get all the user stories including child projects.

I can see Rally UI has option to get the data from Child project. So I believe there must be an option to get this data using above API. (They use projectScopeUp=false&setScopedDown=true which doesn't seems to be working with 
"hierarchicalrequirement" API.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. 
 It seems like you've already found the project scoping docs:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/projectscope.jsp

I think if you just swap your `(Project.Name = "My_Parent_Project")` query to instead use the `project=/project/12345` query string parameter and include `projectScopeDown=true` you should be all set.

Comment: What a conincidence. I already have done exactly this to achieve that. Thanks anyway for your time.